# Start a timer manually in android

Tags: android, timer

I need to use the timer to check for updates at specific interval. The checking regards to current location. However, I need the timer to start after the current location of the user has been obtained. Thus, I need to start the timer manually. Is there a way I can initiate the scheduled task of the timer on the basis of this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use `timer` to get location updates. There already is a way to get updates of user's current location.

You should call the `requestLocationUpdates()` method to get the updates of the `lastKnownLocation`.

The method is like,

```
requestLocationUpdates(String networkProvider, int timeInMillis, int distanceInMeters, this);
```

Where `String networkProvider` could either be `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

You should use it like,

```
LocationManager mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, this);
```

This will get Last Known Location updates after 1000 milliseconds and 100 meters.

And to get the latitude longitude,

```
Location location;
if (mLocMgr != null) {
    location = mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        System.out.println(latitude+" "+longitude);
    }
}
```

Refer **Location Manager** in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This process is much more efficient, I know that. However, can you kindly help me a bit more?
I need to trigger a function call whenever the location is changed, that is whenever the requestLocationUpdates function is executed. What will be the procedure in that case?

Comment: @ankon048 if you use `requestLocationUpdates()` and specify *time* and *distance* then you will automatically receive the location updates after specified time and distance. And it's impossible to use time to get location updates in android.

Comment: Thanks again. Kindly allow me to clarify my question again. The function will allow me to get the location at fixed time interval or specific distance change. But I also need to trigger another method every time requestLocationUpdates() is executed as I also need to check for some other values at every check.
I used the timer to check for the latest location by putting the latest location update function in a handler.

Comment: @ankon048 not sure about that but you should try putting those methods inside `if (location != null)` in my edited answer

Comment: I received the location update from requestLocationUpdate() method and scheduled the other functions in the timer. Its working fine now. Thanks a lot.